# To find the probability of event

Tags: probability

The probability of event X occurring is the same as the probability of event Y occurring. The events occur independently of each other.
 Quantity A:The probability that both events occur. 
Quantity B:The probability that neither event occurs

Comment: There seems to be a great deal of missing information, most importantly, **the actual question**.  This is all information leading up to a question.  Presumably this is one of those "*which quantity is greater?  quantity A, quantity B, they are equal, or there is not enough information*" type questions.  What happens if $Pr(X)=Pr(Y)=1$?  What happens if $Pr(X)=Pr(Y)=0$?

Comment: For me it seems more as if this was a question about how to convert a text into a formular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p := P(X) = P(Y)$

Both events occur:

$ A = P(X) \cdot P(Y) = p^2$

Neiter event occurs (Not $X$ and not $Y$):

$ B = (1-P(x)) \cdot (1-P(Y)) = (1-p)^2$